# cc -o kocka -I/usr/include kocka.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXi -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm -lpthread /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi

Tags: makefile

I get this error when I want to play the make file, but I don't know why.

```
APPS = kocka
OBJ = $(APPS).o
SRC = $(APPS).c

CFLAGS = $(C_OPTS) -I/usr/include
LIBS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXi -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lm -lpthread

application:$(APPS)

clean:
    rm -f $(APPS) *.raw *.o core a.out

realclean:  clean
    rm -f *~ *.bak *.BAK

.SUFFIXES: c o
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

$(APPS): $(OBJ) 
    $(CC) -o $(APPS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

depend:
    makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `libXi` on your machine?  Add a `-L` flag for that directory.

Comment: where I should search this libXi? :-S

Comment: this is a homework, and this makefile it worked in the school, now I installed the freeglut for ubuntu and when I want to compile, I get this error. The problem is that I don't find this libXi :(